Why the oracle database changes the non latin character encoding?
I am using Oracle database with AR8MSWIN1256, and unfortunately I cannot change the encoding to UTF8.
Then I have defined a table with a column type of varchar2
and tried to run sql operations from a Java application.
Based on the character set of windows-1256 it is possible to save characters like ی, that has encoding code EC and its table is mentioned in windows-1256 encoding table. But after the saving when I fetch the data it changes to ي that has encoding code ED. This happens only for a few characters, not all of them.
I have set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 environment variable on client system. The only solution that I found to fix the problem is to change the column type to nvarchar2 to change the column encoding to Unicode and setting the VM options is mentioned in the Persian character encoding in oracle database as follows:
-Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true 
-Doracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals=true

But I do not understand why I cannot save this character correctly in windows-1256. Also, I am confused why the client application must set the defaultNChar=true.

Are you also using orai18n.jar which provides NLS support?

Yes, both ojdbc11.jar and orai18n.jar are added to classpath

The client NLS_LANG is wrong, and it is converting.

@Phil what is the correct NLS_LANG? I tried AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256 and nothing changed.

@Phil Java/JDBC does not use NLS_LANG, setting it has no effect.. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643 S

You should use ى (U+0649,  Arabic Letter Alef Maksura,  &#1609;) instead of ی (U+06CC,  Arabic Letter Farsi Yeh, &#1740;). The latter isn't in cp1256 as is replaced using ي (U+064A,  Arabic Letter Yeh, &#1610;).

@JosefZ thats great, this is exactly what is happening. Do you have any idea how can I tell the java app jdbc to talk with a correct windows-1256 encoding?
